# How to render a React component (ES6 API) directly using ReactDOM?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, react-dom

I'm using the [ES6 classes API of React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html) (by using TypeScript) and want to render a subtyped class of type `React.Component` using `ReactDOM.render()`.

The following code works:

```
class MyComponentProps {
    someMember: string;
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProps, {}> {
    constructor(initialProps: MyComponentProps) {
        super(initialProps);
    }
}

let rootNode = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(
    <MyComponent someMember="abcdef" />,
    rootNode
)
```

Now, given the explicit typing of the constructor in `react.d.ts`, I'd assume I can pass an instance of the MyCustomProps object that populates with initial properties (as done in the above code). But how to render the component then directly without JSX/TSX syntax?

The following does NOT work:

```
ReactDOM.render(new MyComponent(new MyComponentProps()), rootNode);
```

I know I could just use the JSX syntax as a workaround, but as my `MyCustomProps` object is pretty large, I don't want to repeat every member of the `MyCustomProps` object.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `React.createElement(MyComponent, new MyComponentProps())` instead of `new MyComponent(new MyComponentProps())`?

Comment: Indeed, that'll work - I could also tell by looking at the compiled .jsx code which maps the JSX syntax to exactly that syntax. If you post you comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should ues `React.createElement`.
`React.createElement` takes a tag name or component, a properties object, and variable number of optional child arguments.
E.g.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (

      <div><h1>Welcome to React</h1></div>
    );
  }
}
```

Using `jsx` it can be rendered like this

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

In another way(without `jsx`)

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById('app'));
```

A running example -

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div><h1>Welcome to React</h1></div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null), document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
</div>
```

Comment: The last line of code in your answer is what I was looking for, thx!

Comment: Future Googlers: you should change your code to look like this if you are getting `TypeError: this is undefined` at react.js:5045.

Comment: So I have to use `ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(), root)` instead of `ReactDOM.render(<div></div>, root)`? Is there anything can be done that makes TypeScript allow JSX literal in `ReactDOM.render()`